# regex newline character error

Tags: multiline

I am trying to make my regex work across multiple lines and "m" didn't seem to work either. So, my regex is working for 1st line and noT for the following lines.

Comment: An additional note: the **m** flag is used for making the "beginning of line" (`^`) and "end of line" (`$`) characters match those in *each* line. Without it these will match the very beginning and the very end of the string/value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip the `match` part and just do it all in one step:

```
> "the  *text* is to be replaced \n by *text*".replace(/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>');
"the  <i>text</i> is to be replaced \n by <i>text</i>"
```

- `.` matches any character, but it excludes newlines. `[\s\S]` matches any character *including* newlines.
- I changed your search regex to `\*([\s\S]*?)\*`, which non-greedily matches the stuff between the asterisks.
- The replacement string is `<i>$1</i>`. `$1` is replaced with the contents of the first capturing group, which is your text.

Also, because it looks like you're trying to convert Markdown to HTML, try using a pre-made JS converter: http://www.showdown.im/

---

You can use it like this:

```
var str = "the  *text* is to be *replaced \n by* *text*";

alert(str.replace(/\*([\s\S]*?)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>'));
```

Comment: You mean? 
    var str="the *text* is to be replaced \n by *text*";
    alert(newStr.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, '<i>$1</i>');                      should work?! It doesn't... :/ i'm totally new to regex... this doesnt alert anything at all..

Comment: Yep, that's it (but change `newStr` to `str`). I'm testing my JS in a console so I cram everything into one line.

Comment: That does work. However, I was told that the same regex should be used for a string like "* a\n1 *" and it should do the same. But, it doesn't. Can you give me some inputs on this please? And also, \n should be displayed as part of new string. It shouldn't disappear

Comment: @user1727587: `alert()` is a cruddy debugging tool. Don't use it. Grab Firebug for Firefox or Chrome's built-in Inspector and use `console.log()` instead. As for the newline, see my edit.

Comment: It works for * a \n 1* as well. But, the problem that still persists is that of \n being replaced by a new line. I would like to display the \n.

Comment: You're using `alert()`. It isn't being replaced.

Comment: Doesn't display in console.log either. I'm trying it with both. But, even in console.log it displays the part after \n in new line and doesn't display \n.

Comment: @user1727587: The line break is the newline being rendered. Type `a\nb` into the console.

Comment: @user1727587: The line break is there, but it's being displayed as literally a line break. When you write `\n`, it isn't ```\``` + `n`. `\n` is *one* character that is rendered as a line break.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay. So, that means it is actually a part of what is being displayed. But, we don't see it! Great. Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: @user1727587: Yep, it's just a display issue. See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792732/displaying-control-characters-in-chromes-console

Comment: I copy pasted "a\nb" in firefox's console editor. But, even that doesn't display the \n, like you say in that questions of yours. How do I get the \n to display in firefox atleast?

Comment: @user1727587: I typed that into the console and took a screenshot. Not sure how else to help you there.