# Displaying control characters in Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

Is there any way to force Chrome's JS console to display newlines like Firefox?

**Chrome:**

[image]

**Firefox:**

[image]

Possibly a hidden switch somewhere?

Comment: I suppose something like `x.replace(/\n/g,"\\n")` is out of the question? (Or use FF, which seems to do what you want by default.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: That's the behavior that I'm trying to emulate in Chrome. There doesn't seem to be a hidden switch anywhere, though.

Comment: Yeah, I figured. I guess worst-case if you need to copy-paste the value or something you could manually enter a `.replace()` statement as per my previous comment, or define a function to do it so you don't have to type it every time. (Clunky? Yes, I admit it.)

Comment: can you tell us how to display those characters in firefox? I'm around this issue for 20 minutes and I can't get by googling it a good answer for this problem

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira: Firefox stopped displaying strings like this starting with 23.0.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`encodeURI`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) for showing the hidden stuffs.

Something like this `encodeURI("a\nb")` instead of `"a\nb"`.

[image: Chrome EncodeURI]

Answer (score 2):

In node.js, [`require("util").inspect`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) does something very similar.  I haven't been able to find a browser equivalent, though fortunately the [node.js implementation](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/19d29aa0e8136cba87ab6bf1649b91b687e31a7a/lib/util.js#L308) is fairly straight forward:

```
JSON.stringify(value)
    .replace(/^"|"$/g, '')
    .replace(/'/g, "\\'")
    .replace(/\\"/g, '"')
;
```

In your case, just `JSON.stringify(value)` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can stringify the value to get these invisible characters:

```
> JSON.stringify("a\nb")
<- ""a\nb""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
var x = 'a\\nb';
```

EDIT:

You can use hexadecimal character in string.

```
\ = '\u005C'
> var x = 'a\u005Cnb';
> x
<- "a\nb"
> x === "a\nb" is false.
> x === "a\\nb" is true or x === 'a\u005Cnb' is true.
```

You can take a look at links.

http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes
http://code.cside.com/3rdpage/us/javaUnicode/converter.html

Comment: But `x !== 'a\nb'`. I'm just trying to change how the console *displays* `x`, not `x` itself. Firefox's built-in console displays control characters like `\n` as *literally* `\n`. Chrome renders them into actual newlines.

Comment: I've edited my question and added screenshots. That should clear up the confusion.